# how to config Django and how to run Gunicorn workers with cpu performance?

Tags: python, django, performance, server, gunicorn

Im using, `gunicorn django_project.wsgi:application --bind=127.0.0.1:8866 --daemon` as command line to run my django on server with 6 processors and 14gb ram, but I did not setup workers, I am using 2 applications on this server, how can I get maximum performance, using all ram memory and processors.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can pass a command line argument to specify the number of workers you wish to run, see: http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#worker-processes

However, if you wish to programmatically get the number of cores, better pass a parameter to read the configuration from a module, like:

```
gunicorn django_project.wsgi:application -c gunicorn.py.ini
```

And the contents of `gunicorn.py.ini` would be:

```
from multiprocessing import cpu_count

bind = '127.0.0.1:8866'
daemon = True
workers = cpu_count()
```

There is also a common formula used for specifying the number of workers:

```
workers = cpu_count() * 2 + 1
```

See the reasoning behind this on: http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/design.html#how-many-workers

Regarding memory usage, I think there's not much you can do, they're gonna use as much memory as they need. However, there are a couple more things you might try out, to optimize your workers. You can specify the `worker_class` in the configuration file, for instance:

```
worker_class = 'gevent'
```

And test which one suits you the best, see the list of available worker classes on: http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#worker-class

Also, by specifying the `max_requests` option (http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#max-requests), you can force the workers to be restarted after a specified number of requests. This is essentially useful if your code leaks memory for some reason, so when they are restarted, the os will clean up after them.

```
max_requests = 1000  # a reasonable value
```

Comment: Thanks!, can i run also with --daemon ?

Comment: @Softsofter the `daemon` parameter is in the example `gunicorn.py.ini` file above, so yes you can, but you can also pass it through the command line as well, as an extra argument along with the config file.

Comment: Sorry, is True, and thankyou for the answer also with command line.

Comment: @Softsofter if you're satisfied with the answer, please make it accepted. Leaving all the answers you get unaccepted will make other users reluctant to answer your future questions.